# GitHub Pages serves me a blank web page when I try hosting a react page

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, web-hosting

I followed all the outlined steps in the GitHub pages setup for React apps.
The app works fine when I run it locally on localhost, but GitHub just serves me a blank page.

I tried setting the serving branch to both my master and gh-pages branches, but both serve me a blank page.

My package.json settings are as follows:

```
{
  "homepage": "https://ThreadSurfer.github.io/MyPortfolio",
  "name": "MyPortfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-video-js-player": "^1.1.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing or that I can do to get GitHub pages to display my app?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to serve your [`ThreadSurfer/MyPortfolio` `gh-pages/index.html`][1], which only includes:

```html
<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

So... the page remains empty.
[1]: https://github.com/ThreadSurfer/MyPortfolio/blob/gh-pages/index.html